# ionic plus angular routing giving a blank page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i just begin with angular and ionic and i have a problem, routing display blank page , its bein 2 hours , that i'm looking for a solution without found one can someone help me figure out this please. sorry for my bad english

this is my app.js code: am i doin someething wrong?

```js
  angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

   .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
     $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('homepage', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                controller: '',
            }
        }
    })


    .state('itemPage', {
        url: '/itemPage',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/itemPage.html',
                controller: 'myCtrl',
            }
        }
    })

    .state('cart', {
        url: '/cart',
        view: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/cart.html',
            controller: 'myCtrl',
        }
        }
    })

    .state('categories', {
        url: '/categories',
        view: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/categories.html',
                controller: 'myCtrl'
            }
        }
    })


    .state('billingDetails', {
        url: '/billingDetails',
        view: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/billingDetails',
                controller:'myCtrl',
            }
        }
    })


    .state('confirmOrder', {
        url: '/confirmOrder',
        view: {
            '': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/confirmOrder',
            controller:'myCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

});
```

Comment: just use the spell Ionicus-Fixicus lol couldn't resist.

Comment: loool nice one my username is just a trip

Comment: So what are you trying to route to? do you change state?

Comment: yes i tried to changes states but without any results , the home page views is displayed , but for others pages , i've the animation that i changed the page , but all its getting blank, did you notice something that i'm doin wrong?

Comment: I on't see anything wrong with your states at a glance, what do your controllers look like?

Comment: not finding something?

Comment: add your controller as an edit not an answer.

I think you have a problem in your controllers. take a look at my Angular code here https://github.com/joeLloyd/Scripto5000/tree/master/CordovaApp/CordovaApp/js its for an ionic project i did a month ago. It might help you out

Comment: thank you for sharing your work , but i didnt found a way to figure out the issue